# Getting a JavaScript value into a variabe

Tags: javascript, php

My 14 yr old son is working on a Science Project looking at reaction time and age.  He is setting up a little web app to test people - When a page is loaded a timer starts and there is a delay in a STOP button appearing (4 secs for this example). When they click the stop button, the timer stops.
He's done a great job of coding all of that so far.  He is using a piece of JavaScript that he found and has modified it to his needs.
His issue - how to pass the stopped time into a variable and then pass that to another page. He is able to successfully do it if the variable is static ie "Hello."
What is wrong with the function stop(); in this example? He currently gets a [object HTMLSpanElement]

```
var clsStopwatch = function() {
    // Private vars
    var startAt = 0;    // Time of last start / resume. (0 if not running)
    var lapTime = 0;    // Time on the clock when last stopped in milliseconds

    var now = function() {
            return (new Date()).getTime(); 
        }; 

    // Public methods
    // Start or resume
    this.start = function() {
            startAt = startAt ? startAt : now();
        };

    // Stop or pause
    this.stop = function() {
            // If running, update elapsed time otherwise keep it
            lapTime = startAt ? lapTime + now() - startAt : lapTime;
            startAt = 0; // Paused
        };

    // Reset
    this.reset = function() {
            lapTime = startAt = 0;
        };

    // Duration
    this.time = function() {
            return lapTime + (startAt ? now() - startAt : 0); 
        };
};

var x = new clsStopwatch();
var $time;
var clocktimer;

function pad(num, size) {
var s = "0000" + num;
return s.substr(s.length - size);
}

function formatTime(time) {
var h = m = s = ms = 0;
var newTime = '';

h = Math.floor( time / (60 * 60 * 1000) );
time = time % (60 * 60 * 1000);
m = Math.floor( time / (60 * 1000) );
time = time % (60 * 1000);
s = Math.floor( time / 1000 );
ms = time % 1000;

newTime = pad(h, 2) + ':' + pad(m, 2) + ':' + pad(s, 2) + ':' + pad(ms, 3);
return newTime;
}

function update() {
$time.innerHTML = formatTime(x.time());
}

function start() {
$time = document.getElementById('time');
update();
clocktimer = setInterval("update()", 1);
x.start();
$(document).ready(function() { $('#mybutton').delay(4000).fadeIn(0);});
}

function stop() {
x.stop();
//var varTime = "Hello";
var varTime = document.getElementById('time');
    window.location.href = "somephpfile.php?etime=" + varTime;


}
```

Comment: Just try : `var varTime = document.getElementById('time').innerText;`

Comment: your current varTime will return an object (which I believe is a div or p). You have to use .innerText to get the text value inside the object :). Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `var varTime = document.getElementById('time')` is assigning the element to the varible, which is fine and not a bad option however I believe your son only needs the HTML text of that element.

There are two options. The first option keeps the `time` element in the function for possible expansion later.

```
function stop() {
    x.stop();
    var varTime = document.getElementById('time');
    if (varTime) {
        window.location.href = "somephpfile.php?etime=" + varTime.innerHTML;
    }
}
```

Or just extract the required text and send it - even if it is empty.

```
function stop() {
    x.stop();
    if (document.getElementById('time')) {
        window.location.href = "somephpfile.php?etime=" + document.getElementById('time').innerHTML;
    }
}
```

Comment: Happy to help. Good luck with the project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the innerHTML of the element instead if just reading element itself. This can be accomplished by :

```
function stop() {
x.stop();
//var varTime = "Hello";
var varTime = document.getElementById('time').innerHTML;
window.location.href = "somephpfile.php?etime=" + 
}
```